# Set fake version info in Windows

Tags: windows

I want to set fake version info in my Windows programmatically. For example, Windows 7 should be detected as Windows 8 by various software. Is it possible, if I have admin access?

Comment: no it's not; what do you want to do?

Comment: best bet is changing Registry, but why do you want to do so? How about installing a Windows 8 in Virtual PC (or equiv.) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer depends on what checks the software is doing to realize its environment.

The [gettype [link]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190899) variable was used in older versions of Windows, and the %OSTYPE% envvar is available in Windows 7.

It's also possible that the software is speaking with [WMI [link]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394596(v=vs.85).aspx).

This might all be pointless, however, if the software is looking into the .dll and checking the return values of [functions [link]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: By the way, if the software is using DLL function, we can hook it with Detours